# Class instance has no attribute list

Tags: python, list, attributeerror

I have a problem with this code.It run's fine until I ask it to list the songs
It throws this error:

> AttributeError: CD instance has no attribute 'songs'

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import collections
import sys
import re
import os
#import argparse
from optparse import OptionParser


class CD() :


    def _init_(self) :
        self.album = ""
        self.date = ""
        self.songs = list()

    def setAlbum(self, album) :
        self.album = album

    def getAlbum(self) :
        return self.album

    def setdate(self, date) :
        self.date = date

    def getdate(self) :
        return self.date

    def setSong(self, song) :
            self.songs.append(song)

    def getSong(self) :
        return self.songs

db = {}

def listAlbum(option, opt_str, value, parser) :


    file = os.getenv("CDDB")
    f = open(file, 'r')
    artist = " "
    artistPattern = re.compile('^[a-zA-Z]') 
    datePattern = re.compile('^[0-9]') 
    songPattern = re.compile('^-') 
    cd = CD()
    for line in f :
        if line == "\n" and artist != " " :
                db[artist] = [cd]
                cd = CD()
                artist = " "
        elif artistPattern.match(line) :
            artist = line.strip('\n')
        elif datePattern.match(line) :
            line = line.split()
            cd.setdate(line.pop(0))
            str = " "
            cd.setAlbum(str.join(line))

        elif songPattern.match(line) :
            song = line.strip('-\n')

            cd.setSong(song)

    if artist != " ":
                db[artist] = [cd]

    artistList()    

def artistList() :

    count = 1
    for key in sorted(db.keys()) :
        print count, key
        count = count + 1
    reply_artist = raw_input("Choose an artist by entering the number or quit by entering a q")
    if reply_artist != 'q' :
        albumList(reply_artist)

def albumList(reply_artist) :

    reply_artist = int(reply_artist) - 1
    alist =  sorted(db.keys())
    count = 1
    cd = CD()
    album = db[alist[reply_artist]]

    for cd in album :
        print count, cd.getdate(), " ", cd.getAlbum()
        count = count + 1
    reply_album = raw_input("Choose an album by entering the number or enter a to return to artist")

    if reply_album != 'a' :
        reply_album = int(reply_album) - 1
        count1 = 1
        x = album[reply_album]
        for song in x.getSong() :
            print count1 , song
            count1 = count1 + 1

    else :
        artistList()


def main( args ) :

    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-l", "--list" , action="callback", callback=listAlbum, help="List Albums. Must be given alone")

    if len( args ) < 2 :
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()  

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
        sys.exit(main( sys.argv ))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CD` class doesn't have an `__init__()` method, only `_init_()` (watch the ["dunder"](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DunderAlias)).